# Browser ignores query string

Tags: url, browser, query-string

I have a hardware device with an admin console accessed via a web interface. I want to pass a query string to the URL so that the username and password fields are pre-populated. I am doing so as follows but the browser ignores the query string:

```
http://192.168.5.50?username=abc?password=def
```

I have checked the page source and the username and password input fields are called "username" and "password".

EDIT:

I see that I have incorrectly used the character `?` instead of `&` to separate the key/value pairs. Correcting this as follows does not change the outcome. The query string is still ignored.

```
http://192.168.5.50?username=abc&password=def
```

There is a form in the HTML with this definition:

```html
<form name="myform" method="post" action="read" autocomplete="off">
```

Is the POST method incompatible with query strings? If so, is there another method of auto-populating fields?

Comment: Maybe the parameters are sent by using POST and not GET (such as the example). Do you have a form in your html ? What is the method ?

Comment: See edit to original post.

Comment: How are you retrieving the parameters?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Has this question been answered with my updates to the original post?

Comment: No. How do you know it's being ignored?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev When I include the query string in the URL, the username and password fields are not populating.

Comment: Well of course they aren't, they aren't suppose to. You need JavaScript for it.

Comment: Is there a way of dynamically creating the JavaScript required to achieve pre-population of the fields? @PedroMartins has posted some JavaScript but I am not sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a form dynamically and submit it. You url should be something like this:

```
            javascript:document.write('<form name="myform" method="post" action="read" autocomplete="off"><<input type="hidden" name="username" value="abc"><input type="hidden" name="password" value="def"></form><scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript">document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();</scr'+'ipt>');
```

Comment: I can't edit the HTML as that is provided by the device's firmware. What is the full URL including the IP address of the device?

Comment: Can't you add the script code I've posted into your application (not the device's firmware) ?

Comment: I'm not using an application. I am simply accessing the device's admin console via a browser.